# What information must I provide in a Selenium selector question?

Tags: discussion

So you posted a question about a Selenium selector that doesn't work, and now it's been downvoted or closed for lack of information.  What minimum information should you have provided, and why?

Comment: Ideally, reviewers can link **every** under-specified Selenium selector question with a link to the answers to this.  In fact, maybe we need a button for that.

Answer (score 4):

**State what you are trying to accomplish.**

**Show your error message**.  It is not enough to say, "It doesn't work."  Sometimes the error message contains valuable information that will help someone answer your question.

**Show your code**.  Don't just saw what your code does; shows the actual code.  Take the time to format it properly.

**Show the page that your code fails on.**  Sometimes a page is too big to fit into a question.  In that case, who a fragment that illustrates the page's structure.

**State which Selenium version number you are using.**

**State which browser and browser version number you are using.**